Duda sobre el error SyntaxWarning
https://github.com/gondev94/hangmang/blob/main/hangman.py
dejo aquí el codigo a ver si pueden darme una mano con el error de
SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\ '
''', '''
Hola buenas tardes!, gracias por el espacio perdon por molestar.
en las lineas 6 ,14, 22 nose porqué se producen, el código funciona pero me tira ese error

Recuerda colocar siempre el código relevante en la pregunta misma, no a través de enlaces externos. Parte fundamental de la pregunta se perderá si el enlace llega a romperse más adelante.

sucede que \ es una secuencia de escape, lo que se está interpretando de este modo durante tu código.
Vale recordar que una secuencia de escape puede ser \n - salto de línea, \t tabulación, etc.
Para evitar que el código reconozca esto, debes usar una cadena raw.
Para ello, solo debes anteponer r antes de las comillas triples, y en cada etapa. Ejemplo:
stages = [r'''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
 / \  |
      |
=========
''',]

